# GA pageviews don't match BigQuery when unnesting for custom dimension?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

**please, do not flag as a duplicate question; I checked similar questions but could not find a solution**

I am querying GA data in BigQuery and in particular I need to see pageviews by user ID, which is a custom dimension and so needs unnesting. The numbers do not match, though. They do match when I look at pageviews without the custom dimension, so something must be wrong with my query.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

```sql
SELECT
  date AS Date,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN cd.index=2 THEN cd.value
      ELSE NULL
      END) AS `Institution_ID`,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN cd.index=3 THEN cd.value
      ELSE NULL
      END) AS `Institution_Name`
FROM `ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
GROUP BY
  date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is a lateral `CROSS JOIN` when applied to an array. This comes with some consequences: Is the array null, then the cross join results in null - the left sides is not preserved. Your table gets expanded for every entry in the array `customDiemnsions`.

You should always write subqueries on `customDimensions` arrays because semantically it doesn't make sense to expand the table with custom dimensions.

```sql
SELECT
  date AS Date,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=2) AS `Institution_ID`,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=3) AS `Institution_Name`
FROM
  `ga_sessions_*` AS t
GROUP BY
  date
```

Comment: thank you @martin! Really appreciated. thanks for the explanation